# python 3.5 get value out of complicated OrderedDict

Tags: python-3.x, ordereddictionary

using python 3.5, I'm reading a config file (which I have no control over) looking for a value, and it gives me back an OrderedDict.
I tried:

```
l = list(dict.items())
for t in l:
    print(t)
```

that gave back a list of tuples, the value I'm looking for is in l[2] - so I went for t in l[2], that gave back another complicated output:

```
('driver', OrderedDict([('type', 'aws'), ('aws', 
OrderedDict([('upload_credentials', True), ('availability_zones',
OrderedDict([('eu-west-1', [OrderedDict([('zone', 'eu-west-1a'), ('subnet', 
'10.0.0.0/22')])...('ssl_cert_arn', 'arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:12345667777')]))...
```

here is where I got stuck, I've tried using different for looping, recursive, dict.values, etc.. but I can't reach the value I want.
how can I proceed from here assuming I'm on the right track.. 
I'm looking for that ssl value.

Comment: `dpath` might come in handy: https://github.com/akesterson/dpath-python

Answer (score 1):

We're just going to have to recursively scan through the `OrderedDict` until we see a `'ssl_cert_arn'` key.

```
def recursive_scan(d, target):
    if target in d:
        return d[target]
    for v in d.values():
        if isinstance(v, OrderedDict):
             ret = recursive_scan(v, target)
             if ret is not None: #Maybe v[target] is some falsey value like ""
                 return ret
    return None
```

On further reflection, this might work even better as a generator.

```
def recursive_scan(d, target):
    if target in d:
        yield d[target]
    for v in d.values():
        if isinstance(v, OrderedDict):
             yield from recursive_scan(v, target)
```

Comment: wow that was fast, THANK YOU. I did as you suggested, but I don't get anything back, I even added a print at the beginning of the function and still nothing.
recursive_scan(config,'ssl_cert_arn')

and I did print(d) before the first if statement, I appreciate you patience on this one.

if I print(config) outside the function I get the OrderedDict as expected.

what am I missing friend?

Comment: @NaimSalameh not sure if this is the problem, but I made a typo.  it should read `if isinstance(v, OrderedDict):`

Comment: @NaimSalameh if you're using the generator version, you're going to have to pull the result(s) out into a list with something like `list(recursive_scan(config, 'ssl_cert_arn'))`

Comment: That's it !!!! list(recursive_scan(config, 'ssl_cert_arn')) solved the problem.
I can't seem to be able to vote up your answer due to lack of points or something.
I hope I can reach you level some day, that's just amazing to me, magic even.
THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: You can click the little check mark underneath the votes to mark as an accepted answer so that other people who see this page know that it worked for you